# Show that the adjoint of two operators is the sum of the adjoints

Tags: proof-explanation, operator-theory, physics, quantum-mechanics, adjoint-operators

#### Problem

Show that for *any* two operators $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$, the adjoint $(\hat{A} + \hat{B})^\dagger = \hat{A}^\dagger + \hat{B}^\dagger$. Do so using the *integral form* of the definition of adjoint.

---

I know how to show this by manipulating the definition of the adjoint written in *bra-ket* notation, however I'm unable to show the same using the "integral form". Specifically, we're expected to do the following:

By the definition of adjoint:

$$\langle f  | (\hat{A} + \hat{B})^\dagger g\rangle \equiv \langle (\hat{A} + \hat{B})f | g \rangle$$

*...where $\dagger$ denotes the adjoint, and $\star$ denotes the complex conjugate*

This may be re-expressed as:

$$\int f^\star (\hat{A} + \hat{B})^\dagger g = \int \bigg[(\hat{A} + \hat{B}) f\bigg]^\star g$$

We are then asked to re-express the RHS of the equation above such that it is of the form of the LHS. Distributing the complex conjugation, I get:

$$\int f^\star (\hat{A} + \hat{B})^\dagger g= \int (\hat{A} + \hat{B})^\star f^\star g = \int (\hat{A}^\star + \hat{B}^\star)^\star g$$

To get this in the form of the LHS, we must move $f^\star$ to the left of $(\hat{A}^\dagger + \hat{B}^\dagger)$. Unfortunately, it isn't clear to me how this can be done.

Comment: \begin{align*}
\langle(A+B)x,y\rangle_{L^2} &= \int_X (A+B)x \bar y \\&= \int_X Ax\bar y + \int_X Bx\bar y \\&= \langle Ax,y\rangle_{L^2} + \langle Bx,y\rangle_{L^2} \\&= \langle x,A^* y\rangle_{L^2} + \langle x,B^*y\rangle_{L^2} \\&= \int_X x \overline{A^* y} + \int_X x\overline{B^* y}\\&= \int_X x \overline{A^*} \bar y + \int_X x\overline{B^*} \bar y
\\&= \int_X x (\overline{A^*} + \overline{B^*}) \bar y
\\&= \int_X x \overline{(A^* + B^*)y}
\\&= \langle x,(A^* + B^*)y\rangle_{L^2}
\end{align*}

so $(A+B)^* = A^* + B^*$.

Comment: Note nothing here actually requires integrals, and I feel they obfuscate the argument; all that is needed is the additivity of an inner product in both inputs. Indeed, \begin{align*}
\langle(A+B)x,y\rangle_{L^2} &= \langle Ax + Bx,y\rangle_{L^2} \\&= \langle Ax,y\rangle_{L^2} + \langle Bx,y\rangle_{L^2} \\&= \langle x,A^* y\rangle_{L^2} + \langle x,B^*y\rangle_{L^2} \\&= \langle x,A^* y + B^*y\rangle_{L^2}\\&= \langle x,(A^* + B^*) y\rangle_{L^2}
\end{align*}

so $(A+B)^* = A^* + B^*$.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen: I suggest you type your answer in the "answer" box and not in the "comment" box.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, this is a mathematics site, formal manipulation in physicist's notation will simply not cut it.

To do this properly, you need to talk about domains of these operators, which in general are not bounded.   $A^\dagger$ can only be defined (by $\langle x, A^\dagger y\rangle = \langle Ax, y \rangle$ for $x \in \mathcal D(A)$) if the domain $\mathcal D(A)$ is dense in your Hilbert space.  Now the natural definition of the domain of $A+B$ is $\mathcal D(A) \cap \mathcal D(B)$.  Unfortunately, in general there is no reason to think that $\mathcal D(A) \cap \mathcal D(B)$ is dense even though $\mathcal D(A)$ and $\mathcal D(B)$ are.
In fact, this intersection may well contain no nonzero vectors at all.  Thus as a general statement $(A+B)^\dagger = A^\dagger + B^\dagger$ does not make any sense.

For example, let $H$ be a densely-defined self-adjoint operator on a separable infinite-dimensional Hilbert space $\mathcal H$ with purely discrete spectrum,
and $U$ a unitary operator on $\mathcal H$.  Then for a "generic" $U$ in the sense of Baire category (i.e. a member of the intersection of countably many open dense subsets of the space of unitary operators on $\mathcal H$,
$\mathcal D(H) \cap \mathcal D(U H U^\dagger) = \{0\}$.  See my paper [Some Generic Results in Mathematical Physics](http://math-mprf.org/journal/articles/id1023/),  Markov Processes and Related Fields 10 (2004), 517-521.

EDIT: OK, so let's just assume $\mathcal D(A+B) = \mathcal D(A) \cap \mathcal D(B)$ is dense in the Hilbert space $\mathcal H$.  The domain $\mathcal D(A^\dagger)$ is defined as the set of  $y \in \mathcal H$ such that the functional $x \mapsto \langle Ax, y \rangle$ on $\mathcal D(A)$ is bounded.   In that case there is a unique $z \in \mathcal H$ such that $\langle Ax, y \rangle = \langle x, z\rangle$,
and we define $A^\dagger y$ to be  this $z$.  Similarly for $B^\dagger$ and
$(A+B)^\dagger$.

Then it is true that if $y \in \mathcal D(A^\dagger) \cap \mathcal D(B^\dagger)$, then $$\langle (A+B)x, y \rangle = \langle Ax, y \rangle +\langle Bx, y \rangle = \langle x, A^\dagger y \rangle + \langle x, B^\dagger y \rangle = \langle x, A^\dagger y + B^\dagger y \rangle$$
so $y \in \mathcal D((A+B)^\dagger)$ and $(A+B)^\dagger y =  A^\dagger y + B^\dagger y$.  Unfortunately we can't go in the other direction: there is no reason to expect every member of $\mathcal D((A+B)^\dagger)$ to be in
$\mathcal D(A^\dagger)$
or $\mathcal D(B^\dagger)$.  For example, we might have $B = -A$, in which case $(A+B)^\dagger = 0$ with domain all of $\mathcal H$.  So it's still incorrect to say $(A+B)^\dagger = A^\dagger + B^\dagger$, just $A^\dagger + B^\dagger \subseteq (A+B)^\dagger$.

Comment: while I agree the OP needs an extra condition there somewhere to ensure existence (which I doubt is really on the OP, and is probably the fault of the physics book/class they are taking due to the general lack of rigour), I don't feel this post actually answers the question and instead makes an important but tangential remark... it is clear the OP is meant to assume the adjoint can be defined if the statement is to be proved